# What is the basis of the information in Dora Lange's diary?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-detective

In season 1, episode 2 of *True Detective*, Detective Rustin Cohle reads Dora Lange's diary, and the phrases, *"The Yellow King"* and *"Carcosa"* stand out.

What do these phrases mean?

Do they have context outside of *True Detective*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The King in Yellow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_in_Yellow) is a book of short stories by Robert W. Chambers, first published in 1895:

> There are 10 stories, the first four of which, "The Repairer of
>   Reputations", "The Mask", "In the Court of the Dragon" and "The Yellow
>   Sign", mention **The King in Yellow**, a forbidden play which induces
>   despair or madness in those who read it.

The city of [Carcosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcosa) is referenced in the forbidden play.

> The descriptions given of it make it clear that it must be located on
>   another planet, or possibly even in another universe.

In the [Cthulhu Mythos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_King_in_Yellow#Cthulhu_Mythos),

> the King in Yellow is an Avatar of Hastur, so named because of his
>   appearance as a thin, floating man covered in tattered yellow robes.

Comment: Hastur Hastur Hastur.

Comment: Coincidentally, this was just in io9:  http://io9.com/the-one-literary-reference-you-must-know-to-appreciate-1523076497

Comment: Coincidentally, this was everywhere but movies.SE over the last week. I got pulled away before I could answer it myself; your answer is quite satisfactory, though it could theorize how it might apply to the show in a meta-context (the parallels with Cohle's visions and psych-speak).